# Alamofire sending object as parameter

Tags: swift, swift2, alamofire

I'm having hard time doing something simple. The data I want to send is the following:

```
  {
    "nickname":"Rado",
    "social": {
      "data: { 
        "accesstoken":"xx",
        "applicationId":"xx",
        "userId":"xx"
      },
      "type":"whatever"
    }
  }
```

Currently I'm doing that:

```
           let params = [
                "nickname": userName,
                "social": [
                    "type": "whatever",
                    "data": [
                        "userId": accessToken.userID,
                        "accesstoken": accessToken.tokenString,
                        "applicationId": accessToken.appID
                    ]
                ]
            ]

 Alamofire.request(.POST, "url/users", parameters: params, headers: nil)
                .responseJSON { response in
```

}

As a response I get this:

```
{
 "nickname":"Rado",
 "social[data][userId]":"xx",
 "social[data][applicationId]":"xx",
 "social[data][accesstoken]":"xx",
 "social[type]":"something"
}
```

Any advice will be appreciated!

Comment: What is the problem? Can you be more specific?

Comment: Isn't it obvious? The expected result (first code) is different then what I get (third code).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The solution turned out to be really simple. I was missing **encoding: .JSON**

```
    Alamofire.request(.POST, "url/users", parameters: params, headers: nil, encoding: .JSON)
        .responseJSON { response in

    }
```

Comment: Same problem here. JSONEncoding.default was the solution for me. Thanks